# Using Conditional Formatting for Date Comparison between 2 Columns

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to set up conditional formatting to highlight when the difference between 2 columns containing dates is greater than 7 business days, but cannot figure it out.  Example, I would like it to highlight the cell that contains 7/27/18 when compared to the cell that contains 7/14/18 since the difference is greater than 7 business days. Any suggestions?

Comment: would you be okay with a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want any difference greater than 7 BUSINESS days, you will need a list of bank holidays to exclude:

[image]

The formula entered in the conditional formatting is:

```
=OR(NETWORKDAYS(B2,A2,$I$2:$I$3)>7,NETWORKDAYS(B2,A2,$I$2:$I$3)<-7)
```

`NETWORKDAYS` Calculates the difference between the two dates, excluding weekends and any bank holidays supplied.

NOTE:
It does include both supplied dates, so `NETWORKDAYS("23/07/18","24/07/18")` would = 2. Hopefully, this is what you want. If not, you can adjust accordingly.

The OR function simply checks that the difference is not greater than 7 OR less than -7 (in the case that the Start Date is later than the Finish Date, since you didn't specify if that was a possibility or not).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It keeps highlighting the blank cells and not the ones that are actually over 7 days. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: To exclude blanks you can simply wrap the formula with an AND to check for them: `=AND($B2<>"",$A2<>"",OR(NETWORKDAYS(B2,A2,$I$2:$I$3)>7,NETWORKDAYS(B2,A2,$I$2:$I$3)<-7))`. As for it not highlighting the ones over 7 days, are you sure you are entering the formula correctly? Does the range you are trying to highlight, start in B2? If not, you will need to change the cell addresses to suit.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. If it solved your problem, please mark it as the answer by clicking the grey tick to the left of my answer :)